# Input string was not in a correct format with TemplateField in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, gridview, web

I have a template field as shown below in a GridView control.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="CYTotal">            
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblCYTotal" runat="server" MaxLength="20" Width="30" ReadOnly ="true"
                Text = '<%# Bind("CYTotal","{0:#,##0}") %>' Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt"> </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>        
               <HeaderStyle Width="30px" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt"/>
              <ItemStyle Width="30px" HorizontalAlign="Right" />    
          </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am setting the format of the label inside the template field in the RowDataBound event as shown below

```
if (accountTextBox.Text != "Gross Margin")
                {                 
                    lblCYTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:$#,##0}", Convert.ToDecimal(lblCYTotal.Text));
}
else if (accountTextBox.Text == "Gross Margin")
                {                 
                    lblCYTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:P0}", Convert.ToDecimal(lblCYTotal.Text));
}
```

and then, in the RowUpdating event, I am using the below code but it is giving me the error "***Input string was not in a correct forma***t".
I tried removing the "%" sign using “replace” like below but no luck. I also tried using NumberStyles.Currency and NumberStyles.Float.

```
decimal currency = decimal.Parse(lblCYTotal.Text.Replace("%",""), NumberStyles.Any);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Why you don't replace $? because from your code it looks it may possible $ in your textbox. and if it is then it will surely give you an exception.

Comment: thanks Manish, I should've mentioned that I did try replacing both $ and % but still getting the same error.

Comment: ok, But you didn't mention that at which line you get error and what is the text of your textbox when you got error.

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the issue. One of the rows being extracted from the database had a NULL value in it. I made it to show zero(using the ISNULL function) and the error disappeared. I am not sure if this is the best approach but I couldn't figure out any other way.

I have if statements in the code behind to check for NULLS and only format non-null values but it didn't work.